Python Multiprocessing - losing command prompt window
I am running the following Python program to start a few processes to run simultaneously. Each process will run for several seconds. This is being started from a command prompt. But if I interrupt the execution (ctl-C) I often get a console message 'keyboard interrupt' along with a long traceback and the command prompt is forever lost. I must kill the command prompt and start a new one. Depending upon timing, sometimes it will allow new commands to be enterred, but there is no input prompt C\xxx\xxx>.
I expected the ctl-C just to terminate the mainline being executed which would in turn kill the child processes that were running. But this was not the case.
Why can't this program be interrupted without bringing down the Command Prompt from running again?

from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import os
import time

def proc(name):
    print('\nStarting process name:',name, 'PID: ', os.getpid())
    for i in range(1,5):
        print (os.getpid(),': ',i,'\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('\nMain process ID:', os.getpid(), '\n')
    numServers = 3
    serverNum = []
    for i in range(numServers):
        serverNum.append(i+1)
    print ('serverNum: ', serverNum)
    with Pool(numServers) as p:
        p.map(proc, serverNum)

# --> hang here until the processes complete    
    # Execution stops when all processes complete
    print ('Ending mainline task', os.getpid())
    exit(0)

The program output is:

Main process ID: 40536

serverNum:  [1, 2, 3]

Starting process name: 1 PID:  34508
34508 :  1


Starting process name: 2 PID:  2200
2200 :  1


Starting process name: 3 PID:  43476
43476 :  1

34508 :  2

2200 :  2

43476 :  2

34508 :  3

2200 :  3

43476 :  3

34508 :  4

2200 :  4

43476 :  4

Ending mainline task 40536


Wrap the proc function in try-except and re-raise the exception wrapped in Exception():
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time


def proc(name):
    try:
        print("\nStarting process name:", name, "PID: ", os.getpid())
        for i in range(1, 5):
            print(os.getpid(), ": ", i, "\n")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        # Re-raise wrapped in Exception so that multiprocessing.Pool will recognize it.
        raise Exception(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\nMain process ID:", os.getpid(), "\n")
    numServers = 3
    serverNum = []
    for i in range(numServers):
        serverNum.append(i + 1)
    print("serverNum: ", serverNum)

    with Pool(numServers) as p:
        p.map(proc, serverNum)

    # --> hang here until the processes complete
    # Execution stops when all processes complete
    print("Ending mainline task", os.getpid())
    exit(0)

As weird as it sounds, it works. My understanding is that multiprocessing.Pool wraps every subprocess execution in try: ... except Exception: ... to catch errors. However, KeyboardInterrupt inherits from BaseException directly, not Exception, so KeyboardInterrupt is not caught by multiprocessing.Pool.
By re-raising the KeyboardInterrupt wrapped in Exception, it's successfully caught and all processes are stopped.

Here is my approach: Create a handler (a function) to handle Ctrl+C. Note that All processes will receive this ctrl+C, so the handler will be trigger for all processes.
import logging
import logging.config
import multiprocessing
import os
import pathlib
import signal
import sys
import time

logging.config.fileConfig(pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("logging.ini"))


def proc(name):
    logging.info("Starting process name: %r, PID: %r", name, os.getpid())
    for i in range(1, 5):
        logging.info("i=%r", i)
        time.sleep(1)


def ctrl_c_handler(signal_number, stack_frame):
    """
    Control+C handler: terminate all children.

    All processes will receive this handler. For the main process,
    we also terminate the script.
    """
    logging.info("Ctrl+C detected")
    for child in multiprocessing.active_children():
        logging.info("Terminating %r", child)
        child.terminate()

    if multiprocessing.parent_process() is None:
        # This is the main process
        logging.info("All children terminated")
        sys.exit("Ctrl+C detected, terminate abnormally")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a control+C handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_handler)

    logging.info("Main process")
    numServers = 3
    serverNum = []
    for i in range(numServers):
        serverNum.append(i + 1)
    logging.info("ServerNum: %r", serverNum)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(numServers) as p:
        p.map(proc, serverNum)

    # --> hang here until the processes complete
    # Execution stops when all processes complete
    logging.info("End main process")

Here is the content of logging.ini, used in the script:
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(name)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s(%(lineno)d) | %(processName)-24s | %(message)s

Sample output:
root | INFO     | main.py(42) | MainProcess              | Main process
root | INFO     | main.py(47) | MainProcess              | ServerNum: [1, 2, 3]
root | INFO     | main.py(14) | ForkPoolWorker-1         | Starting process name: 1, PID: 135627
root | INFO     | main.py(14) | ForkPoolWorker-2         | Starting process name: 2, PID: 135628
root | INFO     | main.py(14) | ForkPoolWorker-3         | Starting process name: 3, PID: 135629
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-2         | i=1
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-1         | i=1
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-3         | i=1
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-2         | i=2
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-1         | i=2
root | INFO     | main.py(16) | ForkPoolWorker-3         | i=2
^Croot | INFO     | main.py(27) | ForkPoolWorker-2         | Ctrl+C detected
root | INFO     | main.py(27) | ForkPoolWorker-1         | Ctrl+C detected
root | INFO     | main.py(27) | ForkPoolWorker-3         | Ctrl+C detected
root | INFO     | main.py(27) | MainProcess              | Ctrl+C detected
root | INFO     | main.py(29) | MainProcess              | Terminating <ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-2' pid=135628 parent=135626 started daemon>
root | INFO     | main.py(29) | MainProcess              | Terminating <ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-1' pid=135627 parent=135626 started daemon>
root | INFO     | main.py(29) | MainProcess              | Terminating <ForkProcess name='ForkPoolWorker-3' pid=135629 parent=135626 started daemon>
root | INFO     | main.py(34) | MainProcess              | All children terminated
Ctrl+C detected, terminate abnormally

Notes

In the handler, we terminate all children processes
Since all process will receive the ctrl+C, we call multiprocessing.parent_process() and test if it is None, which indicates that this is the main process.

Notes about logging
For multiprocessing and multithreading, I always use logging as opposed to print for a number of reasons

I can configure logging to show the name of the process/thread
I can turn on or off logging at will by editing the logging.ini file
logging library is thread safe. If you use print, sometimes you will see the output of one print statement interrupts the output of another.


It sounds like you're encountering an issue with handling KeyboardInterrupt when using the multiprocessing.Pool to start multiple processes. When you press Ctrl-C, it raises a KeyboardInterrupt, which is intended to stop the program. However, in your case, the Ctrl-C appears to not only interrupt the execution but also leaves the command prompt in an unusable state.

BoppreH had a great solution and answer what is going on. I like his solution.
